# Non-convex function

Tags: notation

What is a non-convex function? Is it a concave function?

> In mathematics, a concave function is the negative of a convex function. A concave function is also synonymously called concave downwards, concave down, convex upwards, convex cap or upper convex. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function

Comment: A function which is not convex.  

Not necessarily concave!

Comment: @Ashkan For quadratic function, are they always the same ?

Comment: Fruits are either apples, pears or none of them. Now we see a fruit that is not a pear. Can we then say that it is an apple? :-)

Comment: f(x,y) = xy is a   quadratic non convex function which is not concave

Comment: @Ashkan If in the one-variable case?

Comment: Then non-convex = concave

Comment: Thank you both Ashkan and Math-fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function which is not convex. Not necessarily concave!

For example $  f(x) = x^3$ which is neither convex nor concave !

But If we only restrict ourself to quadratic functions defined on $\Bbb R$,  $f:\Bbb R \to  \Bbb R$ as OP pointed out in comments. Non convex function is concave. Because $ f'' = a $  must be negative .